# Convert data source to json file in jQuery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

can someone help me convert the json data in js file to json file,

i'm trying to rather have the data included in the js file, make js file read it from json file.

java.js

```
var serverName = {
    "App1": ["Server1", "Server2", "Server3"],
    "App2": ["ServerA", "ServerB", "ServerC"],
    "App3": ["ServerX", "ServerY", "ServerZ"]
}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in serverName[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + serverName[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
```

java.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>

    <select name="targetApp" id="targetApp" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="App1">App</option>
        <option value="App">App</option>
        <option value="App">App</option>
    </select>
    <select name="category" id="category">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    </select>
```

new data file created

data.json

```
{
    "App1": ["Server1", "Server2", "Server3"],
    "App2": ["ServerA", "ServerB", "ServerC"],
    "App3": ["ServerX", "ServerY", "ServerZ"]
}
```

I tried these methods, non of them works.

wont work i get serverName undefined for some reason jQuery cannot set serverName to a global variable.

```
var serverName;

function jsonData(){
        $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {

var serverName = data;

});
}


 function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in serverName[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + serverName[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
```

also this one doesn't work, the serverName will be read in the java.js (inside the function) so the HTML cannot read it, the serverName ill be undefined in the HTML side.

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {

var serverName = data;

function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length === 0) document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (hostId in serverName[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + serverName[value][hostId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }

});
```

any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: convert json to json file???

Comment: @epascarello yes, as you can see in the $.getJSON the file defined is data.json.

Comment: @epascarello just updated the post, added the json file (data.json).

Answer (score 0):

fixed like this..

java.js

```
var serverName = $.getJSON('data.json',function(data){
serverName = data;
});

function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length === 0) document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (hostId in serverName[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + serverName[value][hostId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
```